# How do I check equality of two enum class elements with googletest?

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest, enum-class

I have an object that has an enum type as a member.

```
enum class Color { Blue=1, Green=2, Red=3}; 
struct A {
    int f;
    Color color;
    A(int x, Color c) : f(x), color(c) {}
};

struct B{
     ...
     std::unique_ptr<A> makeObject(size_t index, Color col) {
     ... // other unrelated parsing and verification code
     auto obj = std::make_unique<A>(index, col);
     return obj;
 }
 ...
};
```

I can have two objects like:

```
B b;
auto first = b.makeObject(2, Color::Blue);
auto second = std::make_unique<A>(2, Color::Blue);
```

and compare the two members like

```
 if (first->color == second->color) {...}
```

However, if I write a google test that has something like

```
 TEST(StuffTest, makeObjectTest) {
        B stuffObject;
        auto retStuff = stuffObject.makeObject(1, Color::Red);

        auto testStuff = std::make_unique<A>(1, Color::Red);

        EXPECT_EQ(retStuff->f, testStuff->f);
        EXPECT_EQ(retStuff->color, testStuff->color);
    }
```

the test fails:

```
Expected equality of these values:
retStuff->color
Which is: 4-byte object <62-01 00-00>
testStuff->color
Which is: 4-byte object <11-01 00-00>
[  FAILED  ]...
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: If you're gonna downvote the question then please let me know why. Not much I can learn from negative numbers.

Comment: Output shows garbage, show your test case exactly.

Comment: @ssh To avoid downvotes always give a [MCVE] in your question. As is we cannot reproduce what you have there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Thanks, I've added the test case for clarity.

Comment: Defect is apparently in stuffObject.makeObject that you avoid posting.

Comment: @ssh Without seeing the code of A::makeObject() we can't tell still.

Comment: You wrote a test for `A::makeObject`. The test fails... I think the likely culprit is this member. It would be prudent to show it

Comment: Thanks all. I've added the relevant parts of makeObject (unfortunately I can't show it all). As has been pointed out I'll focus more on investigating  there instead.

Comment: The skeleton of a program you show has no bugs that would cause this problem. The issue isn't with the standard library or google test. The issue is with `// other unrelated parsing and verification code` that you need to debug thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem in how you are checking the values for equality:

```
EXPECT_EQ(retStuff->color, testStuff->color);
```

works exactly as it is expected to do.

Your problem is most likely in the function you call from class `B`

```
auto retStuff = stuffObject.makeObject(1, Color::Red);
```

This function doesn't do what you expect it to do. You have to investigate there, rather than asking if `EXPECT_EQ()` works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The way you check equality of two enum classes in `googletest` is by using `EXPECT_EQ()`.

This test passes:

```
TEST(StuffTest, makeObjectTest) {
    auto retStuff = std::make_unique<A>(1, Color::Red);
    auto testStuff = std::make_unique<A>(1, Color::Red);

    EXPECT_EQ(retStuff->f, testStuff->f);
    EXPECT_EQ(retStuff->color, testStuff->color);
}
```

Some output (clang, macOS):

```
[----------] 1 test from StuffTest
[ RUN      ] StuffTest.makeObjectTest
[       OK ] StuffTest.makeObjectTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from StuffTest (0 ms total)
```

The issue must be in the `stuffObject.makeObject(1, Color::Red)` call as other have pointed out. If you want more help, you'll have to show what this `makeObject` function is doing.